# display woocommerce upsells products under product gallery

Tags: wordpress

can you help me?
We use the following codes for related products, but what do we need to do for upsells?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 25);
function woocommerce_output_related_products(){
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 4,  
        'columns' => 4,  
        'orderby' => 'rand' 
 ); 
    woocommerce_related_products( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', $args ) ); 
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the position only or trying to change args `posts_per_page` and `columns` as well?

Comment: I'm trying to call upsell products set from within the product instead of related products, not position. The code should be revised accordingly.

Comment: That doesn't clearly specify your actual need. however, you can read about the function here https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_upsell_display or can find the function in woocommerce plugin files.

Comment: Yes, I need to adapt the code snippets here to the above codes. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Then you need to clarify what you're actually trying to do in the revision. In your code snippets, you've changed the `$args` and changed the position but in your reply, you're saying **You're not changing the position** Please take your time and edit your original question and write down what are your expectation and output and what you have done so far with related products.

Comment: I want to show upsells products just under the product's image gallery. That's my main question. I discovered listing related products. But I cannot replace this field with upsells products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 24 );
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much. So how can I make this area floating? In addition, there is this. I want to show only 3 products in this area. Is it possible?

Comment: https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/woocommerce_upsell_display You can read the function and see there is a filter `woocommerce_upsell_display_args` that you can use to change the no of posts and columns args.

Comment: And I have **NO IDEA** what you mean by area floating. If you're trying to make it sticky or similar, you'll have to do some research on a similar topic.